Python - Setting elements in multidimensional array in for loop only sets to last value
I have a multidimensional array. I'm trying to use a for loop to change an element in the array.
But when I run the loop, it sets the element of each index I looped through to the last element.
arr = [[0, 0]] * 2
num = len(arr)

for i in range(num):
    arr[i][1] = i
    
print(arr)

prints [[0, 1], [0, 1]] when what I would expect would be [[0, 0], [0, 1]]

The oddest part is when I print the array element immediately after setting it in the array, it prints correctly. It's like once I'm out of the loop, everything changes.
So if I run:
for i in range(num):
    arr[i][1] = i
    print(arr[i][1])

it prints 0 1 0 1 as expected.

As has been explained elsewhere, [[0,0]] * 2 creates a list of 2 references to the same object.
You could try this:
arr = [[0, 0] for i in range(2)]
num = len(arr)

for i in range(num):
    arr[i][1] = i
    
print(arr)

which creates a new list for each element of arr, so does not have the same issue, and produces the desired output.
alternatively, you could condense the list creation into:
arr2 = [[0,i] for i in range(2)]
print(arr2)


Yeah, I looked, but I couldn't find the solution elsewhere. I guess I didn't know the correct phraseology to find it. Thanks for your help.

No problem. In python, this is called List Comprehension more details here. If this answer helped, please consider accepting it.

when you use :

arr = [[0, 0]] * 2

you are taking the same list and putting it inside the list :

["first list" , "first list"]

you can prove that by printing the id of both lists :
arr = [[0, 0]] * 2


print(id(arr[0]))
print(id(arr[1]))

the id for both is the same, all of them are pointing to the same list in the memory.
for that when you edit any one of them, actually you are editing the saved list that they are both pointing to,
every change you make on the first will be shown in the second because they are pointing to the same list.

this explains what's going on, but it would be nice if your answer also provided a solution to the problem

@aemyl the solution is, you do not use this approach, add a new list to the list like this : [[0,0], [0,0]]

I don't need the solution, Thomas Mockler needs it. That's why I gave you the advice to include it in your post

@Mohammedalmalki Thank you for this explanation. What's the purpose of setting it up this way though? Why would someone want lists with the same id inside a list?

@ThomasMockler it is not about who would do that, it is about the method that you have used to repeat the list, this thing means repeating the list 2 times.

@ThomasMockler this is everything about your question , if i answered your question you can accept my answer
